# How long does it take for questions to be taken off hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

It's been a couple days since [my StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915892/while-loop-executing-once-before-prompt) was put on hold, and since then I have made changes that I think would qualify to have it taken "off hold." When do you think higher people will review the question before it's closed completely?

Comment: It is in the process of being re-opened - it isn't a matter of predictable time, but rather a matter of enough people seeing it in the [reopen review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). While it's nice to have the question re-opened, it did draw four answers before it was closed. Were none of those answers useful to you at all?

Comment: I just cast the fourth reopen vote; it needs one more.

Comment: The question is now re-opened. Curious, though, that before it was re-opened, it did not show up in the reopen review queue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days it seems that  when a question **clearly** should be take off “on hold” it done so very quickly, given that the reopen review list is empty most of the time on stack overflow.     A question that is “on hold” is added to the review list when it is edited, then high rep users can:

- Vote to reopen
- Skip (they don’t know what to do with the question)
- Vote to leave it on hold.

Once a give number of people have said “leave on hold” or “skip” the question is remove from the reopen review list, and only people that happen to see the question can vote to reopen it.

Your question is not **clearly** of use to other people, does not have a useful title and take effort to understand – so it has taken longer to remove the “on hold”.   I consider it to be a poor but valid question like most of the questions on stack overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Questions can stay "on hold" indefinitely.  The wording of the "on hold" event is changed to "closed" after a couple of days, but this is a wording change only; questions can be reopened at any time if the community deems them worthy of reopening.